# Flutter toList() is making a list of <dynamic> type

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to render a list of widgets. To do this, I'm creating a list of RowDataEntry objects that looks like this:

```
class RowDataEntry {
  final Map<String, dynamic> values;

  RowDataEntry(this.values);
}
```

I then want to instantiate the list of entries like this like this:

```
final List<RowDataEntry> data = args['data'].subFunds.map((subFund) {
      final name = subFund.parameters["subFundName"];
      return RowDataEntry({"fundName": name, "status": Status('pass')});
    }).toList();
```

However, the "toList()" converts the list into a list of type dynamic, rather than of type RowDataEntry, and so I'm getting a compilation error.

I've tried casting but I can't get it to work. It would be great if someone could show me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks.

EDIT======================

I think the issue is with the args object. It looks like this:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Comment: which error you get

Comment: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Comment: it's because the toList() is casting it to List<dynamic> .... I don't know how to specify that it's a list of type Map<RowDataEntry>

Comment: @Raph117, can you provide a sample of those `arguments`?

Comment: @Owczar sorry for late reply - this question was work related so it was limited how much I could share. Thanks for your help though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `args['data']` is of declared type `dynamic`, there is no type information about `args['data'].subFunds` available at compile time.  Consequently, there is no way for the compiler to infer that `map` even *has* a type argument, let alone that the type argument should be `RowDataEntry`.

To obtain a `List<RowDataEntry>`, you will need to add type information at some point.  The best point would probably be the class of `args['data']` itself:

```
(args['data'] as SomeClass).subFunds.map( /* ... */ ).toList();
```

Presumably, this class declares `subFunds` as a property of type `List<SubFund>`, so Dart can infer both the type of the lambda parameter and the type argument of `map`.

Other options to fix type inference include:

- declaring `args['data'].subFunds` as a `List` or `List<SubFund>`
- explicitly giving `map` a type parameter

Comment: This is it, thank you very much! I ended up declaring subFunds as its own variable and the error went away.

Comment: "Other option No.1" does not work: respData['posts'].map<Post>((item) => Post.fromJson(item)).toList() still produces List<dynamic>, not List<Post>.